# ASP.NET Core 6.0: The sensitive operation DeleteAsync is not properly logged and, therefore, important execution details may be omitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog, checkmarx, asp.net-core-logging

I have a Asp.Net Core 6.0 WebAPI app that uses entity framework core. The app uses Serilog framework

It is registered as

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

with the below configuration

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Debug",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "ApplicationName": "EFCoreRelationshipsTutorial"
    }
  }
```

It logs the details like

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 DELETE http://localhost:35847/Education/a65f7f0c-2a29-4da0-bd4b-d737320730c6 - -

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService: Information: CORS policy execution successful.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint 'DemoApplication.Api.Controllers.EducationController.DeleteAsync (DemoApplication.Api)'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {action = "Delete", controller = "Education"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] DeleteAsync(System.Guid) on controller DemoApplication.Api.Controllers.EducationController (DemoApplication.Api).

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method DemoApplication.Api.Controllers.EducationController.DeleteAsync (DemoApplication.Api) - Validation state: Valid

DemoApplication.Application.Behaviors.LoggingBehavior: Information: ----- Handling command DeleteEducationCommand (DemoApplication.Application.Feature.Educations.Commands.DeleteEducation.DeleteEducationCommand)

DemoApplication.Application.Behaviors.ValidatorBehavior: Information: ----- Validating command DeleteEducationCommand
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Information: Entity Framework Core 6.0.7 initialized 'TrackManagementContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.6+6fa8f3c27a7c241a66e72a6c09e0b252509215d0' with options: NoTracking 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action DemoApplication.Api.Controllers.EducationController.DeleteAsync (DemoApplication.Api) in 496.7454ms

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'DemoApplication.Api.Controllers.EducationController.DeleteAsync (DemoApplication.Api)'

Exception thrown: 'DemoApplication.Application.Exceptions.NotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/1.1 DELETE http://localhost:35847/Education/a65f7f0c-2a29-4da0-bd4b-d737320730c6 - - - 404 - application/json 4634.2334ms
```

During the security scan using **Checkmarx**, it is reported that

> The sensitive operation DeleteAsync is not properly logged and, therefore, important execution details may be omitted.

Should I ask the security team to suppress this issue? Or this is something that can be addressed at the application level?

**Update:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync(Guid id)
{
    await this.mediator.Send(new DeleteProductCommand { Id = id }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return this.NoContent();
}
```

and it is handled like this

```
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(DeleteProductCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...

        await this.productRepository.DeleteAsync(productToDelete).ConfigureAwait(false);

        ...
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted about any `DeleteAsync` call.

Comment: Please don't dump any warning you get from a tool to Stack Overflow. People can't guess what your code does or what the tool complains about from just part of a warning.

Comment: During "the security scan", what security scan? What product are you using to get that warning message? That isn't part of the framework. Check the docs/help for that product.